# How can I use QGIS's Saga watershed algorithm's "Borders" to extract from point cloud las?

Tags: qgis, saga

How can I get the boundaries of the "Borders" returned by QGIS's SAGA watershed algorithm?

So that I can extract/classify the areas inside borders from point cloud .lases?